# What is wrong with my palindrome checker?

Tags: c

I'm trying to check wither a string is a palindrome by checking that each character always equals its "counterpart":

```
int isPalindrone(char *inputString) {
    int string_size = sizeof(inputString);
    int string_length = strlen(inputString);
    int stop = (string_length / 2) - 1;
    int char_size = sizeof(char);
    char *counterpart, idx; // pointer arithmetic: pointers inherently know their own size
    // counterpart of first char is last char
    counterpart = inputString + string_length - 1;

    for (idx = 0; idx <= stop; idx++) {
        if (*inputString != *counterpart) {
            return 0;
        }
        inputString += 1;
        counterpart -= 1;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: So why do you think it isn't working?

Comment: What is going on here? `*inputString += char_size;`

Comment: Remember in C that pointers *inherently know their own size* so adjusting for offsets based on `sizeof(char)` is counter-productive. `x + y` for a given `X* x` means, in effect, it goes up `y * sizeof(X)` bytes, accounting for alignment issues, etc. That is `*(x + y)` is `x[y]`.

Comment: @tadman that was a mistake, I've fixed it to mean what I originally meant

Comment: `counterpart = inputString + string_length - 2*char_size;` does not find the end of the string.  `counterpart = inputString + string_length - char_size;` does but `char_size` is 1 so `counterpart = inputString + string_length - 1` works.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I'm not sure. That's why I'm here.

Comment: The naive approach here is to start with a pointer at the end of the string, compare to the beginning, and then decrement that, increment the other, until they meet. If there's any differences, return failure and exit.

Comment: But you must have some idea of what it's not doing that you want it to do, or vice versa, or you wouldn't be concerned. You should pass along that information, save us guessing.

Comment: Debuggers help *considerably* in working through code like this to see what's wrong. If you've never used one before this is a perfect use-case to learn from.

Comment: @nowsthetime  What I meant was, you clearly think it isn't working but there must be a reason you think that.  Does it fail to compile (what error message?), does it fail to run (what error message?), does it run and crash before completion, or does it just produce the wrong output.  Now that I have compiled it myself I now know it just produces the wrong output.  But it would have saved time if you had said that since you already knew the answer.

Comment: I've now implemented the proper solution. I assumed that `inputString + string_length - 1` would be a pointer to `'\0'` which terminates the string and thus `inputString + string_length - 2` be the last char, but this is clearly not the case.

Comment: strlen() returns a number that doesn't include the '\0'  so that is all you had to fix: `counterpart = inputString + string_length - char_size;`

Comment: @JerryJeremiah That means `sizeof(myString)` does not include `'\0'`, correct?

Comment: strlen() counts the character not including the '\0'  sizeof tells you the size of the type, so for `char z`, sizeof(z) = 1 and for `char x[100]`, sizeofd(x) equals 100 and for `char *y`, sizeof(y) equals 4 - sizeof has NOTHING to do with what is stored in the variable.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a lot more variables than what you really need.

You are using pointer arithmetic, so you can use the pointers to check the condition:

```
int isPalindrone(char *inputString) {
    char *counterpart = inputString + strlen(inputString) - 1;
    while(inputString < counterpart)
    {
        if(*inputString != *counterpart)
            return 0;
        inputString++; 
        counterpart--;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

or you could place the counterpart inside a for loop:

```
int isPalindrone(char *inputString) {
    for(char *counterpart = inputString + strlen(inputString) - 1; inputString < counterpart; inputString++, counterpart--)
       if(*inputString != *counterpart)
            return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: This is the code I'd expect to see. Nice and concise!

Comment: the one on the top is easier to read but I bet the bottom one is slightly faster

Comment: It is basically the same code, I just changed from WHILE to FOR. So I'm almost sure they will have the same performance.

Comment: `inputString + strlen(inputString) - 1` is certainly UB when `inputString[0] == 0`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica nah, in that case the condition in the loop will evaluate to false and it would be considered as palindrome (If he wants to treat that case differently he should add an extra if case).

Comment: @vmp `inputString + strlen("") - 1` is like `inputString - 1` and generates an address outside `inputString`.

Comment: I know, but it never tries to ACCESS/CHANGE the value in that memory position. All I do is compare the ADDRESS.